# how to make django post accept str rather than pk

Tags: reactjs, django, request, axios, foreign-keys

I have relational DB and a file info to post in it.
DB provides 3 entities holding ForeignKey in some attributes.

Entities are:

> **File, WorkFile and WorkFileStage**

My issue is, when I post info of specific file, I must post on those endpoints, but e.g. WorkFile  holds attribute `file = ForeignKey(File)` - it's an id filed. Which makes me `POST` all the File data, then `GET` it for acquring IDs, then POST on WorkFile with those IDs.

THIS IS A LOT OF POSTINGGETINGITERATINGANDPROMISING (as my request are done with axios on react).

What I've tried, is for POST data construct object with just a `file=file_name`, then search it in the DB on the Django side and `serialize.save()`. But POST requires **pk** rather than str for foreignKeys.

With this though process I ended up with:

```
axios.post().then(axios.get().then(axios.post(then))))
```

Is there any easy/good practice way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Django's POST view can accept whatever you want. As for querying your models via related model properties, check the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

In your case it should be something like this:

```
def my_post_view(request, file_name):
    try:
        work_file = WorkFile.objects.get(file__name=file_name)
    except WorkFile.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    ...
```

where `file_name` is passed as a part of your endpoint URL.

Comment: work_file = WorkFile.objects.get(file__name=file_name) - this part i'm aware of. Problem is with passing on the request data with file=str rather than file=id. I forgot to mension it's django rest. I receive error message with smth like "you are suppose to put id in file field, not str".

Comment: EDIT: i wonder if its more of serializer or view thing to convert from file_name to file_id of specific file to have valid work_file serializer to save it in db.